# How to transfer domain to a new Hosting provider while keeping emails on old Hosting provider?

Tags: email, domain, host

So let's say I have a website hosted in Yahoo Small Business with the domain name of 'website.com' as well as emails associated with the domain name, for instance 'email@website.com'.

How would I move the domain name 'website.com' to a different host such as Bluehost, while still retaining the email services at Yahoo Small Business?

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. This is mostly a "explain me how the internet" works question and as such not on topic for this place, which is for professionals. Superuser.com can likely help better.

Comment: In theory: you only need to update the A records for `example.com` and `www.example.com` (and any others you use to host websites)  with the IP-address of the web server from the new provider. In practice: the new provider may have a requirement for full control of the domain to fit in their generic hosting packages